# GPT-3 API Documentation?

Tags: nlp, gpt

Has documentation of the GPT-3 API been made public?

I would be interested in keeping myself up to speed on the API's capability.

Answer (score 1):

No - GPT-3 API is not currently public.

However once you get access, the documentation can be found at https://beta.openai.com/api-ref.